# How can I easily get warm water in a kiddie pool?

Tags: water, temperature, summer

I’ve got the kiddie pool out for my toddler this summer. The water from the garden hose is freezing cold though.  I’m looking for a way to easily warm up the water a bit. The warmth doesn’t need to be maintained; I think that if the water is relatively warm when the swimming commences, that will be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

***Use Solar Power***

Get the longest hose you can find. Connect another hose to it to make it longer if you can.
The sun can heat the water in the hose as it travels through it on its way to the pool.

Lay the hose in the sun. Some put large loops in the hose and lay the loops on a hot place such as a rooftop or dark-coloured pavement such as a drive-way.

Turn on the water enough to fill the hose and stop. Put the end of the hose into the pool and wait until the hose heats up. Then, turn the water on very slowly so fresh water replaces the heated water going into the pool.

While this is happening, cover the pool with a plastic sheet and the sun will keep the water warm, help heat up the water already in the pool, conserve the heated water already in the pool, and protect the water from dirt and leaves that might be blowing around. Use the plastic to cover the full pool after play is over for the day.

In addition, you can use the whole thing as a teachable moment on conservation, radiation, and whatever else you can work into the lesson.

Comment: If you can cover the pool with black or dark plastic, the amount of heat from the sun will help heat the pool quite quickly as well as protect the water from dirt and blowing debris.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I will boil a large pot of water and add it to the water in the kiddie pool to quickly boost the temperature. This doesn’t work for my wife though as it would be a bit heavy for her to carry all the way to the pool.

Comment: Do you add the hot water after the hose water? Because otherwise the hot water might melt the plastic.

Comment: Yes, add it only if there’s already water in the pool

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the layout of your home and garden, you can connect your garden hose not to the cold tap outside, but to an indoor faucet and select the appropriate temperature.

This will of course only work if the distance between the pool and the nearest faucet is smaller than the hose length, but many parents will want the kiddie pool rather close to the house, in order to supervise play and possibly get some work done in the mean time. (Of course no responsible parent will leave very small kids to play alone.)

Comment: A good nozzle will add at least ten feet to the length of hose to get to that pool.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer *and* it will be a great show. You can even make a rainbow, if the sun is right.

Answer (score 1):

Filling the pool in the morning and letting it sit in the sun helps it warm up.

Works best if it’s not cloudy and if you’re able to fill it up a few hours before using it.

Comment: Is there a way to keep leaves and bird poop out of it during those hours? Or do you skim the top before the kids get in?

Comment: That's a downside of this method ... unless you have a large circular piece of flexiglass or something which would still let the light through, I'm not aware of other ways that keep junk out and still let the sun warm it up.

Comment: Maybe you could drape a clear plastic tarp over it right after you fill it, and then remove the tarp before the kids get in. Just make sure to keep the same side "up" every time you do this. The "up" side would be the only one that ever got debris on it. You wouldn't want lay that on the surface of the clean water in the pool!

Comment: I didn’t realize they made clear tarps. Good idea!

Comment: I did a quick Google search and found a "plastic drop cloth" for painting.

Answer (score 1):

To get warm water in the kiddie pool we have found it's the easiest to connect a hose to the hot water in our laundry room. If your laundry area isn't close to a window or door this probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I filled the kiddie pool with water. 
I took several black trash bags and laid them flat on the surface of the water. 
The bags laid nice and flat and remained on the top. With the sun shining brightly,
after about a 1/2 hour I put my hand into the water. The top portion of the water
felt warm while water deeper in the pool felt cold. The bag surface also felt warm.
This seems to work. Of course, if the children are ready to get into the pool, it
might be hard to stop them and so in that case remove the plastic bags and let them 
jump in.